# Basis of polynomials including differentials

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble with finding the answer to the following problem:

Find a basis and the dimension of the following subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

$\{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x] | deg(p) \leq 3, p''(3) + p(5) = 0\}$

I know how to find basis of a polynomial set and how to do it for $p(n) = 0$ but I have no idea how to do it with the double differential there too. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $\deg(p) \leq 3$ means that the elements of your space are of the form
$$
a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3
$$
and if that was the only restriction, then $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$ would be a valid basis, which means the space is of dimension $4$.

However, we also have the restriction that $p''(3) + p(5) = 0$. Evaluating that on the general form above, we get
$$
2c + 6d\cdot 3 + a + b\cdot 5 + c\cdot 25 + d\cdot 125 = 0\\
a + 5b + 27c + 143d = 0
$$
One restriction decreases dimension by one, so our space now has dimension $3$. All we need to do is find three different degree-three-or-less polynomials fulfilling the above condition. For instance, $x-5$ will do. So will $x^2 - 27$ and $x^3 - 143$. And there we have a basis.